# Extracting inline images from PDF using apache-tika and python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, apache-tika

I need to convert PDF documents into XML or JSON format including inline images.

So far, I am able to produce XML using python-tika library.
To reproduce, use test PDF document with inline image, and extract through python-tika module:

```
from tika import parser
xml_data = parser.from_file('test.pdf', xmlContent=True)
print(xml_data)
```

The XML output contains links to "embedded" images like so:

```
<img src="embedded:image0.png" alt="image0.png" />
```

However I do not understand how the image is embedded as the appropriate section as the XML looks like this:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="Compression Lossless" content="true" />
<meta name="Dimension PixelAspectRatio" content="1.0" />
<meta name="tiff:ImageLength" content="833" />
<meta name="height" content="833" />
<meta name="pHYs" content="pixelsPerUnitXAxis=2835, pixelsPerUnitYAxis=2835, unitSpecifier=meter" />
<meta name="tiff:ImageWidth" content="1177" />
<meta name="Chroma BlackIsZero" content="true" />
<meta name="resourceName" content="image0.png" />
<meta name="Dimension VerticalPixelSize" content="0.35273367" />
<meta name="Data BitsPerSample" content="8 8 8" />
<meta name="tiff:BitsPerSample" content="8 8 8" />
<meta name="width" content="1177" />
<meta name="PLTE PLTEEntry" content="index=0, red=255, green=255, blue=255" />
<meta name="PLTE PLTEEntry" content="index=1, red=254, green=254, blue=254" />
<meta name="PLTE PLTEEntry" content="index=2, red=253, green=253, blue=253" />
<meta name="PLTE PLTEEntry" content="index=3, red=251, green=251, blue=251" />
...
```

Anyone has an idea how to turn this embedded code into actual image? I would like to save the images to filesystem as "image0.png", "image1.tiff" and so on ...

Comment: did you get a chance to figure out how to get inline image from pdf through python ? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately not. According to the tika developers, there was an bug that did not export the attachments. The references in XML were not pointing to anything. Check current release, it may hav been fixed already. I abandoned my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try import the unpack function of tika.

```
from tika import unpack

image = unpack.from_file(file, serverEndpoint="http://localhost:9998")
```

The response should have an 'attachment' key. This is where the images are stored.

Answer (score 0):

At the time of posting the issue was recognized as a bug in Tika.